Reset style in QGIS3
I try to erase, make blank, or no-style layer, as you want.
I don't find any option in QGIS, so I try Python but
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils
layer=qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
layer.loadNamedStyle('') 
layer.triggerRepaint()

has no effect. Where is the fail ?

You need to reset the layer's renderer.
from qgis.core import QgsFeatureRenderer
from qgis.utils import iface

layer = iface.activeLayer()

# Set default renderer
geom_type = layer.geometryType()
default_renderer = QgsFeatureRenderer.defaultRenderer(geom_type)
layer.setRenderer(default_renderer)

layer.triggerRepaint()



thanks, but labels, forms and others stay in my style, how to reset all ?
